# Magento 2 Braintree taking too much time to get response

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.4, paypal, braintree

Cart page and checkout page take too much time for some time. After disabling the Braintree extension both pages are loading normally. Sometimes both pages are loading normally with the Braintree extension. So not sure where is the issue.

DevOps team said, "The polling is waiting for information from the external resource mentioned to return any content/data."

Getting this issue from the last two days. Is anyone facing issues with Braintree?